Passing Task as result
I have read many times that NOT awaiting a Task is probably a bug in the code, but I am struggling to see it this way.
Is there any pitfall in not awaiting Task in method PassDoSomethingWoAsync example below ?
I assume that if I need simply pass "the result" of one async method without any further processing like in Task PassDoSomethingWoAsync(string message) => DoSomethingAsync(message), it is better to return Task without async/await keywords to make sure that state machine is not created. It is more efficient than method async Task PassDoSomethingAsync(string message) => await DoSomethingAsync(message)
public class MyEngine
{
    public async Task PassDoSomethingAsync(string message)
        => await DoSomethingAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false); // awaited

    public Task PassDoSomethingWoAsync(string message)
        => DoSomethingAsync(message); // not awaited

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync(string message)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine($"DoSomethingAsync: {message}");
    }
}

I have tested this approach in the simple App below and I cannot figure out what could go wrong. Am I missing something ?
Console.WriteLine("App started");
var engine = new MyEngine();

await engine.PassDoSomethingWoAsync("Without Async");
await engine.PassDoSomethingAsync("Async");

Console.WriteLine("App finished");

Console output:
App started
DoSomethingAsync: Without Async
DoSomethingAsync: Async

I have created fiddle sample with exceptions and even exceptions are handled correctly (caught).

Eliding Async and Await by Stephen Cleary. In this case you can safely elide it.
